# Query to find users that haven't paid?

Tags: t-sql, case

I have the following SQL

```
SELECT CASE
        WHEN B.bookingId = P.bookingId
        THEN 1
        ELSE 0
        END AS PAID
        FROM Booking B
        LEFT OUTER JOIN Payment P ON P.bookingId = B.bookingId
```

This outputs 3 rows; 1, 1 and 0

I would like to extend this query to output the booking details of the `0` value.

How can I do this?

Thanks

Comment: I think we may need some example data, and to see your schema. Also how would you treat partial payments? Also, you haven't identified exactly what data you're looking for.

Comment: What sort of result are you wanting?  What are the 'booking details'?

Comment: atm there is no partial payments, the database could be determined by a `booking` and a `payment` entity. the `booking` entity has a `bookingId`, but the `payment` entity only has rows with users that have paid determined by the `bookingId` in the `payment` entity. atm there are no partial payments

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select * from booking
where booking_id not in ( select bookingid from payment )
```

Comment: I think he wants to also include the 1's though too.  It is hard to tell.

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more clearer, I did want the ones but I can easily determine the rest on the queries. Randy thanks for this, it's a quick and easy query to get what I want!

Answer (score 2):

If you need to have a column when paid == 0, then you will also have the column when paid == 1.

Try this:

```
select
  case
    when booking.bookingId = payment.bookingId then
      1
    else
      0
  end as paid,
  column_detail1,
  column_detail2
from
  booking
  left outter join payment on payment.bookingId = booking.bookingId
```

If you only want to select information when paid is 0, you might try this:

```
select
  paid_flag.paid,
  booking.detail1,
  booking.detail2
from
  (
    select
      case
        when booking.bookingId = payment.bookingId then
          1
        else
          0
      end as paid,
      booking.bookingId
    from
      booking
        left outter join payment on payment.bookingId = booking.bookingId
  ) paid_flag
  join booking on paid_flag.bookingId = booking.bookingId
where
  paid_flag.paid == 0
```

It seems likely that the query above can be optimized.

Comment: +1 Yours works too but I do prefer the other method

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, this will give details on both.  Then you can ignore the 1 details.

```
  SELECT CASE
            WHEN B.bookingId = P.bookingId
            THEN 1
            ELSE 0
            END AS PAID,
            B.details
            FROM Booking B
            LEFT OUTER JOIN Payment P ON P.bookingId = B.bookingId
```

Other wise maybe

```
SELECT CASE
            WHEN B.bookingId = P.bookingId
            THEN 1
            ELSE 0
            END AS PAID,
            WHEN B.bookingId = P.bookingId
            THEN ''
            ELSE B.details
            END AS UNPAIDDETAILS,
            FROM Booking B
            LEFT OUTER JOIN Payment P ON P.bookingId = B.bookingId
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're in SQL 2005+

```
;with cte as (
SELECT B.BookingId, 
        CASE
        WHEN B.bookingId = P.bookingId
        THEN 1
        ELSE 0
        END AS PAID
        FROM Booking B
        LEFT OUTER JOIN Payment P ON P.bookingId = B.bookingId
)
select B.*
from Booking B
inner join cte
   on B.BookingId = cte.BookingId
where cte.PAID = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Because the rows from `Booking` will always be present in the result set (since it's the left-hand table in the JOIN) you can simply include the columns you want the list of columns returned:

```
 SELECT CASE
    B.Column1Name,
    B.Column2Name,
    WHEN B.bookingId = P.bookingId
    THEN 1
    ELSE 0
    END AS PAID
    FROM Booking B
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Payment P ON P.bookingId = B.bookingId
```

This will show the booking details for all records.

If you're interested in only the unpaid records, add something to your WHERE clause to limit the output to those records only:

```
 SELECT CASE
    B.Column1Name,
    B.Column2Name,
    WHEN B.bookingId = P.bookingId
    THEN 1
    ELSE 0
    END AS PAID
    FROM Booking B
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Payment P ON P.bookingId = B.bookingId
    WHERE P.bookingID IS NOT NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT B.BOOKINGID AS ID, 'PAID' AS PAYMENT_STATUS
FROM BOOKING B
WHERE B.BOOKINGID IN (SELECT PAYMENT.BOOKINGID FROM PAYMENT)

UNION ALL

SELECT B.BOOKINGID, 'UNPAID'
FROM BOOKING B
WHERE B.BOOKINGID NOT IN (SELECT PAYMENT.BOOKINGID FROM PAYMENT)
```